# Swap columns in a dictionary file

Tags: unix, sed

I need to change `Finnish-Czech dictionary` into the `Czech-Finnish dictionary`.

I tried this command:

```
sed -ne 's/\([^a-z A-Z]*\) \(.*\)$/\2 \1/ p' finnish-czech.txt
```

But the first back-reference doesn't work. I realized the end of the back-reference is false and instead of taking only first column it takes everything.

Comment: (1) `sed` does not support back-references. (2) I don't see where a back reference is used here. (3) Can you give some lines of example from the dictionary?

Comment: sääennuste předpověď 
säätiedotus předpověď 
tahtoa přát 
taidekeskus centrum 
taivuttaa ohnout 
talvisota zimní 
tapahtua přihodit 
tapahtua stát 
tavara sejít 
tavaratalo obchodní 
tavata setkat 
tavattavissa k 
tavoitella snažit 
terttu hrozen 
terveyskeskus zdravotní 
tiedustella dotazovat 
tiedustella vyptávat 
tienviitta ukazatel 
tietojenkäsittelytekniikka informační 
tietokoneohjelma počítačový 
tili účet (v 
tilinumero číslo 
tilkku kousek

Comment: @hek2mgl They are clearly using grouping and backreferences ? @OP  `[a-z A-Z]*` Is matching all characters(A-Z anyway) and spaces so will match everything on the line if only normal character and spaces are present.PS post the example dictionary stuff in the question

Comment: http://sinivalkoiset.wz.cz/ostatni/finnish-czech.txt  - link from where I downloaded the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The seperator is `<TAB>`:

```
sed -r 's/^([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)$/\2\t\1/p'  finnish-czech.txt
```

Finnish field match( `^([^\t]*)`) then `TAB`(`\t`) then czech filed match (`([^\t]*)$`

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple job for awk:

```
awk '{ print $2 "\t" $1; }' <finnish-czech.txt
```

For each line, this prints the second field, then a tab, then the first field.

One possible complication is that your file seems to have carriage-returns preceding the newlines - you will probably want to remove them with `tr -d '\r'` or similar.